# Optimizing Page Scrapes with cURL. Load testing results

Tags: php, curl, load-testing

We are trying to optimize a page scrape using cURL. Every time we run load testing on the script doing the scrape our load averages go way up. Whenever we do load testing on the page directly the load averages are down. The scrape post login credentials to site, and loads up a list we want to scrape immediately after login.

With scraping - Load Averages in 60s
Without scraping - Load Averages in Teens.

Here is the cURL we are using. We are looking at other problem points, but wondered if there was anything obviously bad with this.

```
$cookieJar = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);
            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar );

            curl_setopt($this->curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, !($cookieJar) ? true : false);
```

I havent shown code, here but we do cache pages. But even with that switched on, it still increases load average. Would curl-multi-exec be viable option or make things worse.

Comment: As you mentioned scraper, check your `parsing code` May be the page size is huge, and its causing the problem. Try running the `curl` with minimum option only for `www.example.com` with no parsing. And check what it comes up with!

Comment: The high load averages are experienced on the machine that we are scraping from.